# laravel single row dynamic value

Tags: php, laravel

laravel single row dynamic value,  i have 2 input column and 1 drop-down column, i am trying to get the value using 1st column drop-down. if i select value from drop-down, automatically show its associated values in 2 other input column.

**my database table**

[image]

**i want to show this value in input column**

[image]

[image]

**my controller**

```
public function data() {
    $datas = Model::all();
    return view('your view name',compact('datas'));
}
```

my view

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class='text-center'>SL-No</th>
            <th class="text-center'>NAME</th> 
            <th class='text-center'>PART-ID</th>
            <th class='text-center'>PRICE</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody> 
        @foreach ($entry->datas as $key=>$datas1)
            <tr>
                <td class='text-center'>{{ $key + 1  }}</td>
                <td class='text-center  text-danger'>
                    <b>
                        <datalist>
                            @foreach ($datas $key=>$datas1)
                                <option>{{$datas1->name}}</option> 
                            @endforeach
                        <datalist>
                    </b>
               </td>
               <td class='text-center success'>{{ $datas1->part_id}}</td>
               <td class ='text-center'><b>{{ $datas1->price}}</b></td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I can't see any code here which would make this view dynamic. What have you tried so far? Are you looking for a frontend or backend solution?

Comment: @ Spholt frontend solution

Answer (score 0):

in your view code you display all rows in table  and you want to display only one row display dynamic depend on  drop-down so you can use ajax :
first: in view

```
<table class="table">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>part_id</th>
    <th>price</th>
</tr>
</thead>


<tbody>

        <tr>
            <td class='text-center' id="product_id"></td>
            <td class='text-center  text-danger' id="product_name">
                <b>
                    <select name="data" id="product-val" onchange="get_product()">
                        <option value="0"> -- select name -- </option>
                        @foreach ($datas as $key=>$datas1)
                            <option value="{{$datas1->id}}">{{$datas1->name}}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                 </b>
            </td>
            <td class='text-center success' id="part_id"></td>
           <td class ='text-center' id="product_price"></td>
        </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script>
     function get_product(){
      var x = document.getElementById("product-val").value;
    $.ajax({
        url: '/home/product/'+x,
        type: "GET",
        datatype: 'html',

    }).done(

        function(data)

        {
            console.log(data.id);
            $('#product_id').text(data.id);

            $('#part_id').text(data.part_id);
            $('#product_price').text(data.price);


        }

    );
   }

   </script>
```

and add new route in web

```
Route::get('/home/product/{id}', 'VoiceController@getproduct');
```

and function :

```
public function getproduct($id){
    $product=Data::where("id",$id)->first();
    return $product;
}
```

on change select it go to ajax get value of select and sent it to function to get needed row then on done i fill table cell with returned data